# Make a list of URLs if webpages contain specific text

Tags: grep, curl

I am trying to make a list of URLs of webpages, based on whether the webpages contain the text "XYZ".

The URLs are of the form:

https://www.website.tld/page.php?var1=???&var2=static

??? is a number starting with 1, incremented by 1 each time, until an error page is encountered (say a page containing the text "ERROR”)

I want to dump the URLs of the positive matches into an output file. I read curl can sequentially scan such URLs, and its output can be passed to grep. However, I am unsure how I can retrieve and save the URL, after the grep output.

Comment: I feel like you're asking "If I'm at a known location and drive following given directions, how do I know where I am?" If you ran `curl`, how do you *not* know the URL?

Comment: I do know the URL, but how do I output it after grepping on the curl output (webpage content)?

Comment: I still don't understand the question.  Given a string, do you know how to output it?  (Hint: `echo` or `printf`.)

Comment: Fetch webpages using curl, determine if the webpages (not URLs) contain the required text, output the URLs of positive matches.

Comment: Rather than adding information in the comments, you should [edit] the question to improve its quality (see How to Ask). All relevant details should be in the question itself – not in the comments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have made a working script. Sharing it in case someone finds it helpful. @nohillside 's answer helped me.

```
#!/bin/bash

count=1

while true
do
    url="https://www.website.tld/page.php?var1=${count}&var2=static"

    text=`curl -s "$url"`

    if echo "$text" | grep -q "ERROR"
    then
        break
    elif echo "$text" | grep -q "XYZ"
    then
        echo "$url" >> matches.txt
    fi

    ((count++))

done
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to generate the URLs without `curl`:

```
for ((i=1; i<1000; i++)); do
    url="https://www.website.tld/page.php?var1=${i}&var2=static" 
    if curl -s "$url" | grep -q XYZ; then
        echo "$url" >> positive-matches.txt
    fi
od
```

Comment: Thank you. I started working on a script, and your answer helped me.

Comment: @halfbytecode I've upvoted this answer but I'd suggest that you also *accept* it (click on the check mark) to show your appreciation as it answers your question and you don't yet have the ability to upvote answers.